# How to Parse arbitrary boolean logic from yaml

Tags: python, parsing, yaml, boolean-logic

I am hoping to save arbitrary boolean logic as deep as a config file user would like to create. So far my yaml file filters look like this

```
RULES:
    1: 
      FILTER:
        - OR:
          - CONDITION1: XYZ        
          - CONDITION1: ABC               
    2: 
      FILTER:
        - AND:
          - CONDITION1: XYZ                  
    3: 
      FILTER:
        - AND:
          - CONDITION2: ABC
    4: 
      FILTER:
        - AND:
          - CONDITION1: ABC
          - CONDITION2: False
    5: 
      FILTER:
        - AND:
          - CONDITION1: ABC
          - CONDITION3: False
```

The python I'm using to implement the yaml rule parser looks like this:

```
#capture user responses to dict USER_RESPONSES
#Load yaml to rule_dict

for rule_i in rule_dict['RULES']:
    print(rule_i)
    all_tests_pass = True
    for filter_i in rule_dict['RULES'][rule_i]['FILTER']:
        print(type(filter_i),filter_i)

        if 'OR' in filter_i:
            test_or_pass = False
            for filter_i_j in filter_i['OR']:
                for filter_i_j_k in filter_i_j:
                    if filter_i_j_k in USER_RESPONSES and USER_RESPONSES[filter_i_j_k] == filter_i_j[filter_i_j_k]:
                        test_or_pass = True
                        break
            if not test_or_pass:
                all_tests_pass = False
                break

        if 'AND' in filter_i:
            test_and_pass = True
            for filter_i_j in filter_i['AND']:
                for filter_i_j_k in filter_i_j:
                    if not (filter_i_j_k in USER_RESPONSES and USER_RESPONSES[filter_i_j_k] == filter_i_j[filter_i_j_k]):
                        test_and_pass = False
                        break
            if not test_and_pass:
                all_tests_pass = False
                break
    print('------------')
    if all_tests_pass:
        print("PASS Filters - This Rule Will Be Applied:")
```

This seems like there must be a better way to store the filter logic which could possibly be complex. I am debating just having the user's write straight python in the yaml. Any thoughts on best approach to place arbitrary custom filters in yaml that will be parsed in python?

Comment: While having the user write straight python could make the system flexible, it's also a potential security issue, depending on your actual use case.

Comment: @jordanm That was kinda my hesitation from just blowing up this approach. Thanks for the input!